# Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

Tags: android-studio

When I run Android Studio, the following message occurs many times:

> Application Installation Failed
>
> Installation failed with message Failed
> to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to
> collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1180297295.tmp/11_app-debug
> using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not
> verify.
>
> It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an
> existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

[image: screenshot of app]

Neither [OK] nor [Cancel] could resolve the problem.

Comment: Event Log:

13:40 Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Failed to collect certificates from /data/app/vmdl1180297295.tmp/11_app-debug using APK Signature Scheme v2: SHA-256 digest of contents did not verify

Comment: I am facing same issue. I run the app in Mi A1 device with OS 9.0 Pie. And In my app, I encrypt data using AES 256 algorythm.

Answer (score -2):

As it is mentioned in the error report, you can resolve this by just uninstalling your app on your emulator or the device you are using and just run the application again on your android studio.

Comment: This will not help all the times